# Ubuntu 18.04.6 nvidia GTX 1060 not work withboth laptop screen and HDMI monitor

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, external-monitor

At some point after an Ubuntu 18.04 update, I lost external HDMI monitor support. I found that Nvidia does not support the monitor any more. To get it working again, I have to use Nouveau display driver.

I can do this by adding `nomodeset` to `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash quiet nomodeset"
```

But now, I can’t load the GUI on the notebook screen, it just displays boot console messages. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Are you able to press `Alt + Ctrl + f4` to enter tty ? If yes post output of `gnome-shell --version` and `sudo systemctl restart gdm.service`

Comment: Yes, I can switch to tty, but the monitor is locked. gnome shell is 3.28.4. sudo systemctl restart gdm.service makes the laptop hanged

Comment: Looks like it is an hardware issue

Comment: Maybe try using a different computer with the same hard disk if you can. Also, try removing that part of the line you added to the grub file.

Comment: Without nomodeset, nvidea driver can access the monitor but it is blank, I can move cursor from the laptop to the monitor

Comment: Although NOT the solution, the method to change to `nouveau` isn't with `nomodeset` (it doesn't load ANY drivers other than a generic VESA mode), the easy method is to open Software & Updates > Additional Drivers and select and apply (then reboot) the Xorg (nouveau) open-source driver. Again, this ISN'T the solution. ->

Comment: **The solution is likely installing/reinstalling the recommended version of the Nvidia drivers for your hardware and making sure Secure Boot is disabled in UEFI (or manually sign the proprietary drivers).**